# Make a book reader using images [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying for the past hours to create a Comic Book online reader to allow my images to load up.
Everything works fine but I use a counter using a increment method basically and it just doesn't work because bringing down the increments breaks the function.

Maybe there is a simpler way? Also jQuery is the most obscure language to learn unlike HTML or PHP, jQuery has a documentation that pretty much has no organization. Its like here's all the stuff now read each one and maybe you'll find yours. My code is below

```
<script>

    $(function manga () {
        var count = 0;
        var images = ["source_images/01.jpg", "source_images/02.jpg", "source_images/03.jpg", "source_images/04.jpg", "source_images/05.jpg", "source_images/06.jpg", "source_images/07.jpg"];
        $("#left").click(function () {
            var img = images[count % images.length];
            ++count;
            $("#manga").attr("src", img);
            //alert("clicked");
            manga();
        });
        $("#right").click(function () {
            var img = images[count % images.length];
            --count;
            $("#manga").attr("src", img);
            //alert("clicked");
            manga();
        });
        manga();
    });

</script>

<title></title>
```

```
<center>
    <img id="left" style="width:10%; float:left; padding:1.3%" src="files/left_arrow.png" />

    <div >
        <img id="manga" style="width:75%; float:left" src="source_images/00.jpg" />
    </div>

    <img id="right" style="width:10%; float:left; padding:1.2%" src="files/right_arrow.png" />
</center>
```

Comment: make count global variable.I think that one of the possibility may be that count initialize to zero every time when this method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your calling your function manga 3 times 
first when it loads
second when your do left click
and third when you do right click

In this your initializing counter to keep track of the images and everytime
your calling function again your initializing it to 0
so your count again starting from 0.

So to avoid it make your count variable global declare it outside the manga() function.

checkout this code

```
<script>
var count = 0;
$(function manga () {
    var images = ["source_images/01.jpg", "source_images/02.jpg", "source_images/03.jpg", "source_images/04.jpg", "source_images/05.jpg", "source_images/06.jpg", "source_images/07.jpg"];
    $("#left").click(function () {
        ++count;
        var img = images[count % images.length];
        alert(img);
        $("#manga").attr("src", img);
        //alert("clicked");
        manga();
    });
    $("#right").click(function () {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            count = images.length-1;
        }
        else {
            --count;
        }

        var img = images[count % images.length];
        alert(img);
        $("#manga").attr("src", img);
        //alert("clicked");
        manga();
    });
    manga();
});
```

```
</head>

<body>

<center>
    <center>
    <img id="left" style="width:10%; float:left; padding:1.3%" src="files/left_arrow.png" />

    <div >
        <img id="manga" style="width:75%; float:left" src="source_images/00.jpg" />
    </div>

    <img id="right" style="width:10%; float:left; padding:1.2%" src="files/right_arrow.png" />
</center>
</center>
```

I changed the position of count variable in both left and right click. And added one if condition in left click so that when the page loads first time and if user click left arrow first it will show last image.
so image src will move from first to last.It will work.

Comment: should I move the images as well or just the variable?

Comment: I did but it seems to go forward once before beginning to go back.
http://chocobento.x10.mx/Chocolate%20Bento%20Publishing/testMangaReader/HTMLPage1.html

Comment: its from right to left so click the left arrow first

Comment: The numbers still work the same, I just have the arrows doing the opposite. Basically the Left arrow does the  count up while the right does the count down. I was just telling you so you can see the effect its having. It stalls before switching from escalating up to down and vice versa. Did you click the link so you can see what I mean?

Comment: Yes I have checked your code and now I have edited it again so it now work as you wanted..Now it is for right to left

Comment: I fixed by switching the math around :) 
Thank you so much you are a life saver! :D
If you read manga my site I am working on is to help artist display manga nice, clean, and professionally :)
Thanks so much :D

Comment: Quick question, how do I prevent the count from going into negatives, it happens if you push back to many times.

Comment: No buddy it will not happen the count will never go to 0 that is why we put if condition so that it will not go below 0;